# заполнить таблицу в mariadb через файл

Tags: python, linux, bash, mariadb

День добрый. Есть пустая таблица и есть данные (например в файле csv), эти данные надо как то в таблицу залить (не через консоль mysql). Подскажите как проще всего это сделать?
Пробовал через скрипт на python, запросы, создания таблиц и бд получается, а именно импорт csv нет. Так же через терминал linux.

Terminal(ошибок нет, но и данные не добавляются):

```
mysql --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=root --password=123 --local_infile=1 -e "use inventory" -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/1.csv' INTO TABLE rtn FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"
```

Python, ошибки не выдает, но данные в таблице не появляются:

```
import mariadb 
import csv

conn = mariadb.connect(
    user="root",
    password="123",
    host="localhost",
    database="inventory")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/1.csv' INTO TABLE rtn FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';")
```

Через консоль mysql заливается без проблем:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/1.csv' 
INTO TABLE rtn
FIELDS
  TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А почему у тебя различаются запросы в коде и в консоли? А программа твоя выполняется там же, где и запускается консоль? Если нет - надо использовать LOCAL.

Comment: *Python, ошибки не выдает, но данные в таблице не появляются* С чего бы им выдаться, ошибкам, если ты их не выводишь?

Comment: @Akina это всё делается на одной машине, там же где установлен сервер бд. Код для консоли не работает в терминале, поэтому он отличается. На Python точно не знаю как сделать вывод результата запроса от СУБД

Comment: *Код для консоли не работает в терминале* Вот с этого места поподробнее. Сервер БД вообще не знает, кто ему прислал запрос. Так что или терминал добавляет что-то от себя, или есть различия. И потом, "не работает" - это фраза для бабок на лавочке, а от технического специалиста мы должны видеть точное описание - точный текст сообщения об ошибке, например.

Comment: @Akina да, действительно, запрос то должен быть одинаковый везде. С терминалом разобрался, перепечатал запрос руками и нормально стало работать, видимо что то где то лишнее было. Python пока не победил, пробую разные нагугленные варианты но каждый вариант пишет "Cursor doesn't have a result set".

Comment: *каждый вариант пишет "Cursor doesn't have a result set"* На `cur.execute(...)`? или позже, на другом операторе?

Comment: @Akina да, print(cur.fetchall()) пишет Cursor doesn't have a result set

Comment: Вот рабочий вариант импорта csv в таблицу через терминал, может кому пригодится: mysql --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=root --password=1234 --database=inventory --execute="LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/1.csv' INTO TABLE rtn FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';"

Comment: Ну так LOAD DATA не возвращает записей! какой ещё fetch? делай fetchwarnings и смотри, были ли предупреждения и ошибки.